# How to retrieve specified fields using services?

Tags: 8, services

Using services we can retrieve list of all nodes with different filters and we can get a specific node as well. But is there any way we can specify the fields we would like to retrieve ?

Eg: `api/node/[nid]?fields=field3`,`field6` => It should return only the mentioned fields of the given nid

And when we specify *fields=all* it should return all fields of the node.

What is the best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in option in Services 3.x that i am aware of, try any of these;

1. [Views Datasource](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource)
2. [Services Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_views)

**Views Datasource**

> Views Datasource can be thought of as a userland complement to the
>   work going on in the Services and RDF APIs as a site operator only
>   needs to know Views to be able to create datasources in the different
>   formats.

**Services Views**

> It has currently two features:
>   - Create view based resource creating Services display in a view
>   - Execute any view of the system via views resource call

Views Datasource

Comment: Hi Nikhil,
Thanks for the reply.
I am already using 'Services Views' but, both of these modules give additional style formats in views. What I am asking is different..through the api, we should be able to specify what fields to display.